# Formatting an interval as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I have two columns of DATETIME and I would like to show their difference as `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss'`. My assumption is that the interval would never get negative.

My search led to:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEDIFF(`to`, `from`), " ", TIMEDIFF(`to`, `from`))
```

But it gives out:

```
0 00:00:00
```

But I was hoping to get:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Given that DATEDIFF returns an integer, there's no way that can be converted to year/month/day - it will depend on the start date (30 days may be 1 month, or it may not be...) Do you have to do this in SQL? If you could do it client-side instead, it would be simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for a SQL-only solution. Otherwise it would be pretty easy. I'm writing an SQL file and giving it to `mysql < ./format.sql` console application and it supposed to show it as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the intervals with repeated calls of [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [TIMESTAMPADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd):

Example:

```
SET @to = CAST('2014-10-03 12:00:00' AS DATETIME);
SET @from = CAST('2011-05-12 13:12:44' AS DATETIME);

-- get the full years
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, @from, @to);  -- 3
-- get the months, without full years in between
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, @from, @to), @from), @to); -- 4
-- get the days, without all months in between
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @from, @to), @from), @to); -- 20
-- get the hours, without all days in between
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @from, @to), @from), @to); -- 22
-- get the minutes, ...
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @from, @to), @from), @to); -- 22
-- and the same for the seconds
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @from, @to), @from), @to); -- 16
```

See it in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2dd8/2)

Concatenating the result from those values is straightforward:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, @from, @to), 4, '0'),
    '-',    
    LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        MONTH, 
        TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, @from, @to), 
        @from), @to), 2, 0),
    '-',
    LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        DAY, 
        TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @from, @to), 
        @from), @to), 2, 0),
    ' ',
    LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        HOUR, 
        TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @from, @to), 
        @from), @to), 2, 0),
    ':',
LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        MINUTE, 
        TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @from, @to), 
        @from), @to), 2, 0),
    ':',
    LPAD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        SECOND, 
        TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @from, @to), 
        @from), @to), 2, 0)
);
-- result: 0003-04-20 22:47:16
```

See it working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2dd8/7).
Please consider that the result may easily be something like `0001-02-30 01:12:14` ...

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice if you use one SELECT with CONCAT and also LPAD for zeros. Just for future references.

Comment: @Mehran: That's an valid cause. Done.